# Transferring Data from multiple users to one Server from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, database, data-transfer

I made a Java program, that should run on multiple Pcs (as a Minecraft Mod). this Program should send data to a C# application that i made, that is running on my Pc or later on a raspberry pi. The Data, that the Java Program gives out looks something like that:
"DiscordTag;Server;Type;PlayerName"
Is there any good way to do this?
I have never done something like that, so a hint, that seems obvious could help me.

Comment: you can transfer a file or you can implement some sort of server in your c# side and a client in your java side (REST maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like RESTApi would work for you? Basically send data in json form from one application to the other. That way your applications can communicate in real time.

You C# application will basically be a server and respond to REST messages from the java clients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there an easier way to do this? i only want to transfer small strings like every 15 minutes or so and an RESTApi seems a bit overkill.